# Android emulator in Windows 10 has no border

Tags: android-emulator

My Android emulator is working very well in Windows 10, but without any border so I can't move it. It was not problem until the emulator starts and appears in the corner of the screen. When the emulator starts, I can see only half of the emulator, and I can't move it.

How can I make the border visible or even move the emulator?

The problem is that the emulator does not appear fully on the screen, only half of it appears as shown in the image below and I can't move it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't normally a Windows-centric area, and generally questions about emulators would fall into the programming off-topic arena. You can probably bring the emulator to the forefront in Windows 10 by the following KEYBOARD entries (and you should know them anyway by heart). The System Menu which, appears at the top-left of windows, can be accessed even WITHOUT A MOUSE! You can move windows into the current viewport with the keyboard + careful arrow usage.

1. Activate the specific window you want to move - you may be able to click with the mouse.
2. KEYBOARD entry to activate the System Menu: Alt + Spacebar
3. KEYBOARD entry to activate the MOVE command: Down-arrow + Enter
4. KEYBOARD entry to move the window to your liking: Arrows: Left,Right,Up,Down until you can see the menubar(s) you need.
5. KEYBOARD entry to leave the window in position: Enter
6. Continue with mouse, menus, etc. to find command related to positioning the window size permanently.